# IndexWriter in Lucene 3.5 is slower?

Tags: lucene

We are upgrading our search infrastructure from Lucene 2.3.1 to Lucene 3.5. I am in the process of load testing and I could find that Lucene 2.3.1 could index 32,000 docs per second, whereas Lucene 3.5 could index only around 17,000 docs per second.

Indeed, both of them use the standard analyzer and the default settings. Is 3.5 slower because it indexes more details and thereby resulting in a faster search? Ours is a log management product and the speed of indexing is highly important.

Ok, cutting the long story short, will the slower indexing of 3.5 result in a higher search speed?, if not, what else should I fine tune to improve the indexing speed?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ImproveIndexingSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed) on Lucene wiki?

Otherwise, please share some details on your setup so that we can help you:

- how often do you commit?
- what MergePolicy, ramBuffer size, and mergeFactor do use?
- how many indexing threads do you spawn?